# How to put labels on top of Venn diagram circles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=4cm}}
  \node [venn circle = white] (A) at (0,0) {$5 \hspace{1cm}$};
  \node [venn circle = white] (C) at (0:2cm) {\hspace{1.7cm}$2$\\\\ \hspace{1cm} $2$};
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$5,3$};   
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Above the left circle I'd like the label “Prime factors of 75” and above the right “Prime factors of 60”.
How can I do this? Should I use a different code for the Venn diagram to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `label` parameter for your nodes and set where you want them to be placed:

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 

\tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=4cm}} 
\node [venn circle = white] (A) at (0,0) [label={[xshift=-1.0cm, yshift=0.3cm]{\footnotesize Prime factors of 75}}] {$5 \hspace{1cm}$}; 
\node [venn circle = white] (C) at (0:2cm) [label={[xshift=1.0cm, yshift=0.3cm]{\footnotesize Prime factors of 60}}] {\hspace{1.7cm}$2$\\ \hspace{1cm} $2$}; 
\node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$5,3$};

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```